# How do I redirect input and output with PyCharm like I would on the command line?

Tags: pycharm, io-redirection

With the command line if I am running a python file I can enter:

```
python filename.py < filename.in > filename.out
```

Is there a way to mimic this behavior in PyCharm?

Comment: You should pick up Vu Anh answer as accepted one https://stackoverflow.com/a/39482389/248616

Comment: @NamGVU in new python 2018.3.4 you can set "redirect input from:" in the debugger PyCharm settings and the output can be redirected as presented below by yossico, stackoverflow.com/a/39482389/248616 modifies the original script which is not intended,

Answer (score 46, accepted):

(added in Pycharm 5)

In the `Edit Configurations` screen under `Logs` tab check the option:
`Save console output to file` and provide a **FULL PATH** to the outputfile.
thats it - works like a *py-***charm**

[image]

Comment: Note that this will redirect output _including standard error_, and so is not a true equivalent of `> output.txt`.

Comment: @yossico How can I append to the file instead of overwriting it?

Comment: And also for PyCharm 2017.2, this output log setting is not available either

Comment: For people who are not able to locate it, `Edit Configurations` is present under the `Run` menu.

Answer (score 5):

### Redirect input file to stdin

You can load content to stdin by using `StringIO`

```
import StringIO
sys.stdin = StringIO.StringIO('your input')
```

So if you want redirect input from file, you can read data from file and load it to stdin

```
import StringIO   
input = "".join(open("input_file", "r").readlines())
sys.stdin = StringIO.StringIO(input)
```

In case you want to take filename as first system argument

```
import StringIO   
filename = sys.argv[1]
input = "".join(open("input_file", "r").readlines())
sys.stdin = StringIO.StringIO(input)
```

Screenshots:

Main Program
[image]

Debug Configruration
[image]

### Redirect stdout to output file

Similar idea as below sample code

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(outputFile, mode='w', buffering=0)
#skip 'buffering' if you don't want the output to be flushed right away after written
```

Comment: You're suggesting to change the program to read input from a file. The question was about managing this "from the outside"; see the other answers about the Run-configurations.

Answer (score 4):

As for the input, you can provide space separated input parameters in `Script parameters` field under `Run->Edit Configurations`. There's no direct way in pyCharm to redirect the output to a file unless you are using some wrapper class whose sole job is to write the wrapped module's output to a file.

Answer (score 3):

In PyCharm 5 (or even previous versions), you can do this by modifying the script parameters in Edit Configurations window. In that box, write

`< filename.in`

`> filename.out`

on separate lines

Comment: @yossico You are right. I do not see this option any more in the current version of PyCharm. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't put any loading code in the python file, the solution for me was to:

1. Install [BashSupport](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4230-bashsupport) plugin
2. Create file `launcher.sh` with content:

   `python filename.py < filename.in > filename.out`
3. In PyCharm create bash configuration: `Run -> Edit Configurations -> + Bash`
   and put `launcher.sh` as Script name

Comment: This can run the bash script only - we cannot debug though

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34104617/183174) was not accepted / working , but in PyCharm 2017 the following approach works:

In the `Run/Debug Configuration` window , open the `Script Parameters` dialog and enter your input and/or output files on separate lines like this ( with quotes ):

```
< "input01.txt"
> "output01.txt"
```

[image: script parameters dialog]

Notice that I have `>>` here , this appends the output to `output01.txt` so that I have it all over multiple runs .

I don't see why this approach wouldn't work with older versions of PyCharm as it executes the following line using this configuration:  [image: PyCharm Command Line]

Also this approach works with a remote interpreter on a Vagrant instance , which is why that command is using ssh .

Comment: I'm using PyCharm 2017.2 and this is not working for me.

Comment: you'll have to give specifics ...try copy pasting what I have there , then change the file names inside the quotes . also be sure those file paths are correct ( at least the input ) .

Comment: I guess I missed the quote. Will try again and back to us later

Comment: I've just tried and it's not working in PyCharm 2017.2 - my sample code to use is here https://github.com/namgivu/hackerrank/tree/master/_archive_/input/170802_1617_input_sample_faster

Comment: that looks correct , how do you know it isn't working ? is there an error message ? you have a lot of duplicate run configs , are you sure you're running the correct one ?

Comment: I start the debug to see if I can read from input file instead of entering values thru the console

Comment: Of course I am sure what I am doing. I right clicking the .py file to start the debug