# Golang to redirect fmt.Scanf to read from file instead of os.Stdin

Tags: redirect, go, stdin

Normally when we call `fmt.Scanf()` in Golang, the program will read from standard input stream i.e. `os.stdin`

I want, by Golang code, to make `fmt.Scanf()` to reading from a file stream - similarly to a [technique in Python here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39482389/248616).

Please note that we have the piping workaround at command line level; here I'm looking for in-Golang code solution.

If you know how to get there, please share.

p.s.

I guess it requires us to

- read from file stream and store in a string variable `bytes`
- assign `bytes` to `os.stdin` stream

Though I'm a Golang newbie and my [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?newwindow=1&biw=1855&bih=965&q=golang+redirect+fmt.Scanf+to+read+from+file+instead+of+os.stdin&oq=golang+redirect+fmt.Scanf+to+read+from+file+instead+of+os.stdin&gs_l=psy-ab.3...117763.129164.0.129422.35.33.0.0.0.0.370.3709.5j18j3j1.27.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..9.5.732...0i7i30k1j33i21k1j33i160k1.0.hd_2NcoGc08) is not very helpful so I asked here.

Comment: Perhaps you can use fmt.Fscanf instead. You can give it any io.Reader you like.

Comment: @Peter Thanks but I seek for `fmt.Scanf` solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Setting a file as `os.Stdin`

If this is truly what you want: `os.Stdin` is a variable (of type [`*os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File)) which you can modify to your liking, you can assign a new value to it. Opening a file and assigning it to `os.Stdin`, [`fmt.Scanf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanf) will read directly from that file. For details, see [Fill os.Stdin for function that reads from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365221/fill-os-stdin-for-function-that-reads-from-it/46365584#46365584).

Here's a complete example which opens a file named `a.txt`, sets it as `os.Stdin`, then calls `fmt.Scanf()` to read a `string` value from `os.Stdin` (indirectly from the `a.txt` file). The code below also handles saving and restoring the original value of `os.Stdin`. It is not needed here, but it serves as an example, and it's also good habit to restore global things you modify temporarily.

```
f, err := os.Open("a.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()

oldStdin := os.Stdin
defer func() { os.Stdin = oldStdin }()

os.Stdin = f

var s string
if _, err := fmt.Scanf("%s", &s); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error reading: %v", err)
}
fmt.Println("Read:", s)
```

Note that you can also redirect `os.Stdout` to a file like:

```
f2, err := os.Create("out.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer f2.Close()

oldStdout := os.Stdout
defer func() { os.Stdout = oldStdout }()

os.Stdout = f2

fmt.Printf("This will be written to the file: %s", f2.Name())
```

### Using `fmt.Fscanf()`

An easier, better alternative would be to use [`fmt.Fscanf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fscanf) which is analogue to `fmt.Scanf()`, but here you can also pass an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) to read from, and `os.File` implements `io.Reader`, so you can directly pass a file to it.

### Redirecting a file to the standard input of your app

Another option would be to redirect a file to your app as its standard input when you launch your app. For example:

```
go run myapp.go < a.txt
```

This command will start your app, streaming the contents of the `a.txt` file to the standard input of your app. And so `fmt.Scanf()` will read the contents of the `a.txt` file.

Comment: I need to stick with `fmt.Scanf()` i.e. the challenges on hackerrank.com do not use `fmt.Fscanf` in their submission template

Comment: @NamGVU Then the 1st and 3rd solutions are viable for you. If you can't control how your app is started, then maybe only the 1st.

Comment: And also, I need to stick with non-piping from command line too i.e. need a solution within Golang code

Comment: @NamGVU Ok, still, you can use the 1st solution.

Comment: I'll focus on your 1st suggestion - may you give details of how to archive that; I'm so nob that I can't tell myself the which code is correct/best-fit

Comment: Brilliant answer ever. Accepted a thousand times ^^